# /etc/crontab what does "test -x" stand for

Tags: shell, cron

In my `/etc/crontab` file I have:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *  * * * root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6  * * * root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6  * * 7 root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6  1 * * root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

I know what this does in practice but I don't understant the command lines.

Man "test" doesn't help at all:

```
test - check file types and compare values
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From FreeBSD's `man test`: [1]

```
 -x file       True if file exists and is executable.  True indicates only
               that the execute flag is on.  If file is a directory, true
               indicates that file can be searched.
```

So the cronjobs test if there is `anacron` installed [2] (i.e., there is an executable called anacron in the expected place) and run something **if not** - namely the scripts in the respective `/etc/cron.*` folders.

(1) [Bash's builtin `test` has the same `-x` option](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html)

(2) Anacron is a cron replacement designed for computers that are not always running, <s>i.e., if there's a job to be run *weekly*, it will be run *weekly, relative to the uptime of the computer*, which means it will not run every, say, friday, but every 24*7 hours of uptime.</s>  (**Edit** I got it all wrong, see comments)

Comment: That's not a very accurate description of what Anacron does.  It doesn't measure uptime.  It simply runs jobs whose scheduled run time occurred while the computer was off as soon as you turn the computer back on.  Regular cron skips a job if the computer isn't on at the instant it was scheduled to run.

Comment: oh, then I got it wrong (or mixed it up with what fcron does? there was another cron replacement...). thanks for the heads-up

Comment: @cjm afaik anacron needs its own config-files. So you have to explicitly configure anacron-jobs.

Comment: @Nils, I wasn't trying to imply otherwise.  I'm just pointing out that "every 24*7 hours of uptime" is completely wrong.  Anacron's schedule is based on calendar time, not uptime.

Comment: @cjm If the scheduled runtime of multiple jobs occurred when the computer was off and the computer has now turned back on, will the jobs be executed in ascending order of scheduled time?

Answer (score 5):

You may be familiar with `[ -x <filename> ]`.
`test -x <filename>` does the same thing, test if this file exists and is executable.

Answer (score 2):

As quoted in the man page, test is much similar to eval, it evaluates a conditional expression expr and exits with the return status. Often encountered cases, test is used to determine the type of the file as an expression in which cases it is used to check for a return of either true or false case.
In your crontab, `test -x filename`, where filename is used as expression. This is also equivalent to `[ -x filename ]`. This will return true if the file is present and is also executable(bit is set).
`man test` gives definite details of the varied options for type to evaluate the conditional expressions on the files and other valid shell expressions.

For example:

`test -1 -gt -2 && echo yes` would print yes.

`test 0x100 -eq 1`
     error--> test: integer expression expected before -eq

Comment: Do you mean the `eval` statement in sh/ksh/bash/zsh?